# Complex analysis residue calculus

Tags: complex-analysis

Would you know how to calculate:
$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{6+\sin^2(z)} dz$?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want to do it an easier way that doesn't require complex analysis?

Comment: Maybe find out poles?

Comment: I don't know what to try. I am lost.

Comment: It seems like you know what to try. Just give it your best attempt. My personal opinion is that I don't like self defeatest attitudes like "I am lost." It means you don't give your intelligence enough credit - you are not lazy so don't act that way. What makes a pole? How can you set an equation to find where the poles are? Try writing these up and editing your post, I will not downvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An hint:**

Write $\sin z= \frac 1 2 (w-\frac{1}{w})$ and note that:

$$2\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{6+\sin^2(z)} dz=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{6+\sin^2(z)} dz=\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{6+(\frac 1 2 (w-\frac{1}{w}))^2}\frac{1}{iw}dw$$

where $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$.

Use finally the Residue Theorem to compute the last one.

Comment: Why is there equation, with $\pi$ and $\2pi$? :)

Comment: @lida I edited the question. That equation holds because $\sin^2(z+\pi)=(-\sin(z))^2=\sin^2z$ thus $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{6+\sin^2(z)} dz=\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{6+\sin^2(z)} dz$

Comment: Ok. I tried to do one fraction of it and find out poles, but there are terrible numbers.

Comment: In denominator there is: $z^4 - 26z^2+1$

Comment: If I want to find poles, it is very complicated.

Comment: Can I ask how to use the Residue Theorem to compute the last one? :)